# SQL SERVER 2008 R2 Transaction Snapshot Isolation Level Not Working As Expected

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, transaction-isolation

I created a database called 'test_isolation' and created a table 'person' with data

```
name    age
----    ---
test1    1
test2    2
test3    3
test4    4
test5    5
test6    6
```

Now the database is altered to allow snapshot isolation in **session1**

```
ALTER DATABASE test_isolation
SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON
GO
```

Now I create a transaction in **session 2**

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT;
GO
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT * FROM PERSON
GO
DELETE FROM PERSON WHERE name = 'test6'
GO
SELECT * FROM PERSON
GO
```

The results are as expected. (Note we haven't committed this transaction yet!)

Now I execute the following query in **session 3**

```
SELECT * FROM PERSON
```

The query in session 3 keeps on running infinitely which means the table is locked.

If I go back to session 2 and commit the transaction.. I'm able to run the query on session 3 and the results are as expected.

Transaction isolation level **SNAPSHOT** is not supposed lock the table right? Am I doing something wrong or my understanding of transaction **SNAPSHOT** isolation is wrong?

Please help..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must explicitly declare `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT` in session three, otherwise session 3 will still operate as READ_COMMITTED and block on the update.

This option can also be set at the database level to replace READ_COMMITTED with SNAPSHOT.

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

Comment: +1 from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb(v=vs.80).aspx: `Setting the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON option allows access to versioned rows under the default READ COMMITTED isolation level. If the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT option is set to OFF, you must explicitly set the Snapshot isolation level for each session in order to access versioned rows.`